# Dropped Xbox One controller turning off

Tags: windows-8.1, game-controller

So I managed to drop my controller and it's not working properly anymore. The problem is that when I try to turn it on (Xbox one button), it turns off the instant I let go of it. If I keep the button pressed, it works as it should and syncs with the remote. I have also tried connecting to a wire but then Windows 8.1 doesn't recognize it.

Is there any chance of saving it or is there something in the electronics that is broken?

Comment: Sounds like you broke it

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"
~Serious question though, replace batteries?

Comment: @AthomSfere As I wrote I CAN turn it on but the moment I release the button, it dies. And the batteries are fully charged.